# How do I check which browser I'm using?

Tags: browser

Some context: I'm using Desire, and it bugs me that it adds "http://www." when I type a word into the address bar. I just want to search...

The application I'm using is called "Internet". Is it something tailored to HTC? Is it based on Chromium?

Comment: can you give some context?  Do you mean programatically or by looking at it?

Comment: @Nathan - sorry, context added.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Settings - Applications - Manage Applications - All - Select the icon you use and this will give you all the information about the program

Answer (score 1):

The default, built-in Android browser doesn't do a lot of advertising of itself at all (as it doesn't really need to). Most 3rd party browsers put their name and/or logo in as many places in the UI and menus as possible. If you can't see any browser names or logos in the interface then you're probably using the default built-in browser.

To see if a specific web browser on your phone is being used as the default for any actions, then go into **Settings** -> **Applications** -> **Manage Applications** -> **All**, and find it in the list (the built-in browser will be called either "Browser" or "Internet" in the list, depending on your version of Android). When you the browser's icon in that list the Application Info screen should appear, and if that browser is currently set to be the default, then you should see a section labelled "**Launch by default**" where it will say "*You have selected to launch this application by default for some actions*". If the browser isn't set as default that section will say "*No defaults set*".

If you want to change the default browser, just click the <kbd>Clear defaults</kbd> button on the one that is currently acting as the default, and next time you click a web link you should get a box pop-up asking you which browser to use, and giving you the option to set that as the default.

It's hard to tell from your question, but it's worded in a way that could also just be asking for more specifics of what the default, built-in browser is, in which case this previous question should help you out: [Android browser](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4271/android-browser)