# Default browser / update to support google cloud printing

Tags: browser, google-chrome-to-phone

Is the default browser on the android platform Chrome? And if so, does anyone have an idea how to update it or get it to work with the Google Cloud Printing?

In the settings area I am not able to see anything for the Cloud printing options.

If the default browser on a Android phone is not Google Chrome, What is the best way to get Google Chrome installed so I can use the Cloud Printing? And make it the default browser!

Comment: For the "is the default browser Chrome" part, see this previous question http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4271/android-browser

Answer (score 2):

It's not Chrome and you can't install Chrome.  Chrome and the Chromium project have been coded for the x86 architecture, i.e. the PC, and all the UI code is specific to either Windows, Linux, or Mac.

Comment: Thank you. How about a plugin to work with the default browser to config the Google Cloud printing. I have searched but I may not be searching for the right key word.

Comment: @Chris The Android browser has fairly limited plugin support, so I wouldn't hope for anything.  Firefox Mobile has plugins though, so maybe in the future there will be one for Cloud Print.

Comment: Do you know anything about this app, Cloud Print BETA?

Comment: @Chris Wow, I'm really surprised [that](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.pauloslf.cloudprint) exists.  It's free, so I'd give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

You can download and install Firefox Mobile and then add an extension/add-on that allows printing pages with Google's Cloud Print: http://www.androidcentral.com/cloud-printer-extension-enables-printing-firefox-mobile

In Honeycomb (Android 3.0) Chrome bookmarks sync with the device, so additional Chrome features, if not the entire browser, may make the leap to Android in the future.