# Was Firefox ever the default browser for Android?

Tags: browser, internet, chrome-for-android, default-applications, firefox-for-android

Before I bought my Android, I heard that Firefox was its default browser. Upon noticing that this is not the case, I had assumed that the Internet browser on the Android was Google Chrome, but I just installed that today. Was Firefox ever the Android's default browser, and what is it now?

Comment: No it was never the default browser.

Comment: What's the current default browser? Feel free to post an answer so that I can best answer it.

Comment: I love when people -1 without a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox was never the default Android browser. The actual default browser is based on the open-source WebKit engine, which also powers the Safari browser on desktops, laptops and Apple's iOS-based mobile devices.

In the other hand, Chrome is based in Chromium and offers more options and performance than the stock browser.

Comment: You can read [this similar post](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4271/android-browser) and [here](https://www.webkit.org/blog/142/android-uses-webkit/) for some more information about the webkit choice by Android.

Comment: Chrome also uses WebKit.